# How do I take screenshots and video in Halo?

Tags: halo-3

I see all these beautiful halo videos on the internet, how do I take in-game videos and pictures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Video:

[This lists all sorts of various methods for recording 360 game footage](http://hubpages.com/hub/Guides-to-Recording-Xbox-360-Gameplay-to-Desktop-or-Laptop). It would take a while to list them all; go through and figure out which one suits your situation best based on the equipment you have and the definition of your TV.

As for PC, you might want to look into buying [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/download.php).

Screenshot:

On the PC, you can take a screenshot by pressing the print screen button on your keyboard.

On the Xbox, you might want to use a digital camera or look into using video capture hardware as detailed [here](http://www.ehow.com/how_5015867_screenshots-xbox.html).

Answer (score 6):

For Halo 3, simply use the in game Theater mode, and upload it to your file share. Then download it from your file share on bungie.net, found by typing your gamertag into the search box.

Comment: I can't tell anymore; is he talking about Halo 3 or Halo?

Comment: @Mana: "beautiful" - I think we can rule out Halo 1, anyway :P

Answer (score 1):

For PC you can use [xfire](http://www.xfire.com/) - this little program allows you not only to take screenshots and videos (and you can assign to those functions keys which you want) in most of games but it is as well a communicator.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also a Halo gamer, and I often take screenshots from Halo. Some people will use a hotkey to print the screenshot. But I find that PrntScrn button is not the best way, especially if taking screenshots is a part of work.

There are dozens of good screen capture tools and web-sites on the 'net. As for me, I prefer programs, because a site can lose a screenshot you take from the game and you'll never restore it. The one I used is easy to use and can help you  - [take screenshot on pc](http://www.screenrecord.net/take-screenshot-on-pc.html) with high quality.

Answer (score 0):

I use a program called [Video Decompiler] which can do that .
I take screen shots from videos & Movies easily. 
I also can take continuous screen shots automatically (as it has that option).
when U need it U can set the program to automatically take screen shots 
from the program each period of time ..
 U can try it here:- http://www.Robust.ws